# Overflow text into the margin with CSS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How could I prevent this text to jump into a new row and make it overflow into the margin? I've tried with text-overflow but it does not seem to work..Ideally it would appear overflowed from the left margin and disappear into the right margin. Any suggestions perhaps?

```css
.section-overflow {
  background-color: green;
  font-size: 2rem;
  text-overflow: clip;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="section">
      <p class="section-overflow">Lorem - Ipsum Lorem - Dorem - Lorem Ipsum - Lorem Dorem Ipsum - Lorem - Dorem - Lorem Ipsum </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to add `white-space: nowrap;` to your CSS. I would also change your `text-overflow: clip;` to `overflow: hidden;`:

```
.section-overflow {
  background-color: green;
  font-size: 2rem;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Here is the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/t2fh3wmo/

Answer (score 1):

```
<div style="overflow:auto;">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="section">
      <p class="section-overflow">Lorem - Ipsum Lorem - Dorem - Lorem Ipsum - Lorem Dorem Ipsum - Lorem - Dorem - Lorem Ipsum </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</div>
```